# iOS - points, pixels and printing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am creating a UIImage that I want to print using iOS. The printing type will be

```
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
```

or in other words, using regular paper.

As far as I read, iOS will print at 72dpi. So, if I want to print a UIImage with a 2x3 inche size on paper I need to create this image with 144 x 216 points, but how much is it in pixels for that UIImage? or in other words, which size should the image has?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that the 72dpi is actually saying 72 pixels. so your image size of 144 x 216 is actually the size you would want to print. The only reason the UIImageView is measured in points rather than pixels is because of the different screen resolutions. The original iPhone has the same size screen as the 4s, but the screen of the 4s has a LOT more pixels in it. Apple used points so that it is easier to program for all of the devices. Check out this link:  http://www.scantips.com/basics1a.html i just read through it and i hope it will answer your question. I apologize if i confused you even more, I'm just trying to help! :)

Comment: Yes, I know about this stuff. My problem is that I think this 72 is really DPI on the iOS printing stuff. So, if 72 is DPI, 72 pixels are required to draw one inch but, on the other hand, if I print PDF files, they are generally measured in points, cause some stuff inside is vectorial. At this point I am working with images, but I will work with PDFs too. So, I ended without knowing how many pixels I really need.